# ObservableCollection Items won't show up on Add-Method in ItemsControl /w Caliburn.Micro

Tags: c#, xaml

Hello stackoverflow people!

I consult you in deep desparation. I'm using Caliburn.Micro and am trying to implement a feature which shows Messages to the user.

I have a class MessageCenterViewModel which has an ObservableCollection of MessageViewModels and therefore holds all the current Messages to show up:

```
[Export(typeof(MessageCenterViewModel))]
public class MessageCenterViewModel : PropertyChangedBase, IShell
{
    private ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> messages;

    public ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel> Messages
    {
        get{ return messages; }
        set { messages = value; }
    }

    private string title;

    public string Title
    {
        get { return title; }
        set
        {
            title = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(title);
        }
    }

    public MessageCenterViewModel()
    {
        Messages = new ObservableCollection<MessageViewModel>();
        Title = "MessageCenter:";
    }

    public void AddMessage(MessageViewModel msg)
    {
        Messages.Add(msg);
        msg.Expired += (o, e) => RemoveMessage(msg);
        NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => Messages);
    }

    public void RemoveMessage(MessageViewModel msg)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() => Messages.Remove(msg)));
    }
}
```

The view looks like the following:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MessageCenter.Views.MessageCenterView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:views="clr-namespace:MessageCenter.Views"
         xmlns:viewModels="clr-namespace:MessageCenter.ViewModels"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300"
         Background="#727F94">
<Grid>      
        <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Messages}" Height="auto">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:MessageViewModel}">
                    <views:MessageView/>
                </DataTemplate>   
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>        
        </ItemsControl>


</Grid>
```

The MessageViewModel looks like this

```
[Export(typeof(MessageViewModel))]
public class MessageViewModel : PropertyChangedBase,IShell
{
    public event EventHandler Expired;

    protected virtual void OnExpired()
    {
        EventHandler handler = Expired;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    private string message;

    public string Message
    {
        get { return message; }
        set
        {
            message = value;
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(()=>Message);
        }
    }

    public MessageViewModel(string message,int expires = 0)
    {
        Message = message;

        if (expires == 0) return;
        var timer = new Timer(expires);
        timer.Elapsed += (o, args) => OnExpired();
        timer.AutoReset = false;
        timer.Start();
    }
}
```

and the corresponding view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="MessageCenter.Views.MessageView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="35" d:DesignWidth="500" Margin="3">
<Grid>
    <Border BorderBrush="White" BorderThickness="1" Background="#34FFFFFF" CornerRadius="8">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="30" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" MinWidth="30"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Width="16" Height="16" Grid.Column="0" Source="..\Icons\baloon_blue.png"/>
            <Label x:Name="Message" Content="{Binding Path=Message}" Foreground="White" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" FontSize="12" FontFamily="/Fonts/#Roboto Medium" />
            <Ellipse Width="14" Height="14" Stroke="Black" Grid.Column="2"/>
        </Grid>   
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

When I add MessageViewModels in the ctor of MessageCenterViewModel they are displayed properly but when i try to add MessageViewModels after that they won't show up. What am I doing wrong? I appreciate your help!

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. Failure didn't lie within the code I posted rather than in multiple MessageCenterViewModels which weren't displayed.